# How to run a build in Travis when the build is in an infinite loop

Tags: travis-ci

I currently have a build of an application that is set to run infinitely. It is designed to run on a Raspberry Pi as a service, so it will continuously be running.

Whenever I try to test it on Travis-CI, the infinite loop portion draws an error even though the file builds correctly since it is running infinitely. Is there any way to stop this error, or do I have to remove the ability to run the build from the .travis.yml?

```
language: cpp
compiler:
  - clang
  - g++
script:
  - make
  - cd main
  - ./jsonWeatherPrediction
```

I would expect it to error, I'm just not sure of a current way to stop it without removing `- ./jsonWeatherPrediction`

I don't know if this will help, but the build is located at https://travis-ci.org/DMoore12/json-weather-prediction

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most any reasonable CI workflow, the job should have well-defined start and finish. Your software you are testing *may* run forever, but your tests should not. So, first, I suggest re-thinking how you run your build.

Looking at build such as https://travis-ci.org/DMoore12/json-weather-prediction/jobs/474719832, I see that you are simply running your command (which raises a different question: The command is printing the same output forever in a tight loop. Is this the desired behavior?).

For testing, you need a different kind of behavior, one that can be tested (e.g., take input from STDIN or a command-line flag, print, and terminate).